# How to put in a new array min value from another array comparing values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I´m trying to do this exercise with a forEach function.
I have to create a new array with a very big integer.
Then I have to compare its value with each value from an array and if the value from the array which I loop it is smallest than the very big integer, the new Array get this value.

Below it is my code.

How can I do? Thanks for your help.

```js
var myArray = [3344, 34334, 454543, 342534, 4563456, 3445, 23455, 234, 262, 2335, 43323, 4356, 345, 4545, 452, 345, 434, 36, 345, 4334, 5454, 345, 4352, 23, 365, 345, 47, 63, 425, 6578759, 768, 834, 754, 35, 32, 445, 453456, 56, 7536867, 3884526, 4234, 35353245, 53244523, 566785, 7547, 743, 4324, 523472634, 26665, 63432, 54645, 32, 453625, 7568, 5669576, 754, 64356, 542644, 35, 243, 371, 3251, 351223, 13231243, 734, 856, 56, 53, 234342, 56, 545343];


myArray.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
  let myArrayAux = [500000];
  if (value[index] < myArrayAux)
    myArrayAux = value[index];
  console.log(myArrayAux);
});
```

Comment: do you have a wanted result as well?

Comment: What do you mean by `value[index]`?

Comment: `value[index]` makes no sense. If you read the documentation of `forEach`, you will see that `value == myArray[index]`. Also `myArrayAux =` will overwrite whatever `myArrayAux` was. You need to do `myArrayAux.push(value)` so you actually *add* to that array. Also `< myArrayAux` makes no sense. It should be `< myArrayAux[0]`.

Comment: you need to add the actual and desired output also to the question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.I just want that newArray show me 23 which is the smallest value from the main array.

Comment: so 'myArrayAux' isn't an array at all, but just the smallest number? or is it an array with a single value in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```js
var myArray = [3344, 34334, 454543, 342534, 4563456, 3445, 23455, 234, 262, 2335, 43323, 4356, 345, 4545, 452, 345, 434, 36, 345, 4334, 5454, 345, 4352, 23, 365, 345, 47, 63, 425, 6578759, 768, 834, 754, 35, 32, 445, 453456, 56, 7536867, 3884526, 4234, 35353245, 53244523, 566785, 7547, 743, 4324, 523472634, 26665, 63432, 54645, 32, 453625, 7568, 5669576, 754, 64356, 542644, 35, 243, 371, 3251, 351223, 13231243, 734, 856, 56, 53, 234342, 56, 545343];

let auxNumber = 500000; // or  auxNumber = [500000] if it is an array; 

myArray.forEach(value => {
  if (value < auxNumber) // auxNumber[0] if it is an array; 
    auxNumber = value; // auxNumber[0] if it is an array; 
});

console.log(auxNumber); // auxNumber[0] if it is an array;
```

Comment: Thanks Igor!! It was a great help.

Comment: why is `myArrayAux` initialized as an array with one number inside, then later just set to a number and not an array at all?  The first comparison of `value < myArrayAux` is meaningless if `myArrayAux` is `[ 500000 ]`